# Setting static IP address

Tags: iphone, network

How do I set a static IP address on a iPhone 5s running iOS 11.0.3?

Have looked in Wi-Fi but could see nothing about setting static IP address.

Thanks

Elaine

Answer (score 3):

Settings → Wi-Fi, tap the **i** on the currently-connected network, choose Configure IP and set to Manual, then set the IP Address, Subnet Mask and Router.